# PHP MySQLi prepared statement is deleting the wrong row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a script, where one of the features should be to delete a row in the table, however when I try to delete the row it ends up deleting the WRONG row.

The code in my script is as follows:

```
<?php

session_start();

include '../includes/conn.php';

$verified = $_SESSION['verified'];

if($verified !== true){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])){

    $query = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM inventory WHERE ID=?");
    $query->bind_param('s', $_POST['id']);
    $query->execute();

}

if(isset($_POST['desc']) && isset($_POST['mcost']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['rrp']) && isset($_POST['loc'])){

    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
    $date = (string)date("l jS \of F Y");

    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO inventory (Description, MaterialsPrice, Price, RRP, Location, Date_Created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $query->bind_param('ssssss', $_POST['desc'], $_POST['mcost'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['rrp'], $_POST['loc'], $date);
    $query->execute();

    header("Location: inventory.php");

}

?>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Encanto Jewellery - Inventory</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            @import url(../includes/tablestyles.css);

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

            $desca = array();
            $mpa = array();
            $pa = array();
            $rrpa = array();
            $loca = array();
            $datea = array();

            $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Description, MaterialsPrice, Price, RRP, Location, Date_Created FROM inventory ORDER BY ID desc");
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($desc, $mp, $p, $rrp, $loc, $date);

            while($query->fetch())
            {
                $desca[] = $desc;
                $mpa[] = $mp;
                $pa[] = $p;
                $rrpa[] = $rrp;
                $loca[] = $loc;
                $datea[] = $date;
            }

        ?>

        <form action="" method="POST" name="insert">

            <div class="col" style="border-style: solid solid none solid;">

                <div class="row">

                    <b><p>Description</p></b>

                </div>

                <?php

                    for($i = 0; $i < count($desca);  $i++)
                    {
                        echo '<div class="row"><p>' . $desca[$i] . '</p></div>';
                    }

                ?>

                <div class="row">

                    <textarea style="width: 99%;" rows="1" name="desc"></textarea>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col">

                <div class="row">

                    <b><p>Price of Materials</p></b>

                </div>

                <?php

                    for($i = 0; $i < count($mpa);  $i++)
                    {
                        echo '<div class="row"><p>' . $mpa[$i] . '</p></div>';
                    }

                ?>

                <div class="row">

                    <textarea style="width: 99%;" rows="1" name="mcost"></textarea>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col">

                <div class="row">

                    <b><p>Price</p></b>

                </div>

                <?php

                    for($i = 0; $i < count($pa);  $i++)
                    {
                        echo '<div class="row"><p>' . $pa[$i] . '</p></div>';
                    }

                ?>

                <div class="row">

                    <textarea style="width: 99%;" rows="1" name="price"></textarea>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col">

                <div class="row">

                    <b><p>RRP</p></b>

                </div>

                <?php

                    for($i = 0; $i < count($rrpa);  $i++)
                    {
                        echo '<div class="row"><p>' . $rrpa[$i] . '</p></div>';
                    }

                ?>

                <div class="row">

                    <textarea style="width: 99%;" rows="1" name="rrp"></textarea>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col">

                <div class="row">

                    <b><p>Location</p></b>

                </div>

                <?php

                    for($i = 0; $i < count($loca);  $i++)
                    {
                        echo '<div class="row"><p>' . $loca[$i] . '</p></div>';
                    }

                ?>

                <div class="row">

                    <textarea style="width: 99%;" rows="1" name="loc"></textarea>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col">

                <div class="row">

                    <b><p>Date Created</p></b>

                </div>


                <?php

                    for($i = 0; $i < count($datea);  $i++)
                    {
                        echo '<div class="row"><p>' . $datea[$i] . '</p></div>';
                    }

                ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <input type="submit" value="Insert" style="height: 24px;" />
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>

        <div class="col">

            <div class="row">

                <b><p>Delete</p></b>

            </div>

            <?php
                for($i = 0; $i < count($datea);  $i++)
                {
            ?>

            <div class="row">

                <form action="" method="POST">

                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />

                </form>

            </div>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance, looking forward to your answers,

Comment: How do you create the links / buttons, whatever html element which posts the ID to delete to this script?

Comment: FYI: Is ID an integer? If so, use `$query->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);`

Comment: @Loïc look in the bottom <div id="col">

Comment: Eh, didn't see the scrollbar, nevermind, I'm getting tired...

Comment: @Ray ... changing it to $query->bind_param('i', intval($_POST['id'])); worked...

Comment: why dont you select the id in the select query and instead of $i pass that id in the hidden for delete ?

Comment: @ProgrammingTurtle cool, I made it an answer, feel free to mark it correct...

Comment: The way you are doing now once a row is deleted then on next loop the id value will not be in order i.e. 1,2,3....n so again on delete it will delete the  wrong row !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is ID an integer? If so, use

```
$query->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);
```

Also, I suspect you're still be deleting the wrong element.  Try these changes:

1. ADD ID to the query and bind a variable to it:

   ```
      $ids = array();
      // other stuff...

   $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, Description, MaterialsPrice, Price, RRP, Location,   Date_Created FROM inventory ORDER BY ID desc");
       $query->execute();
       $query->bind_result($id, $desc, $mp, $p, $rrp, $loc, $date);

       while($query->fetch())
       {
           $ids[] = $id;
           $desca[] = $desc;
           $mpa[] = $mp;
           $pa[] = $p;
           $rrpa[] = $rrp;
           $loca[] = $loc;
           $datea[] = $date;
       }
   ```
2. Then when you generate your delete elemnts, iterate over the $ids array:

   ```
    <?php
           foreach($ids as $delete_id){

       ?>

       <div class="row">

           <form action="" method="POST">

               <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $delete_id; ?>" />
               <input type="submit" value="Delete" />

           </form>

       </div>

       <?php } ?>
   ```

Comment: @ProgrammingTurtle I would advise against selecting the wrong answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense if my answer fixed his issue, how is it the wrong answer?

Comment: It cannot fix any issue. Anyone who have knowledge can see that.

Comment: Yes the delete form is generated using a loop and then by passing $i in the hidden field. This would lead to a bigger problem once a row is deleted and will delete wrong row again. So in the hidden field the ID of the table row should be passed.

Comment: @Ray if your only concern is reputation points you can snatch from this fraud - so be it.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty See my edits, I didn't see the delete loop at the bottom.  That's a mess...

Comment: @ProgrammingTurtle I made some more suggestion.  Your delete element loop won't work they way you expected.

Comment: @Ray yes its a mess the code he was trying as for($i = 0; $i < count($datea);  $i++){} and by adding $i in the hidden field which is completely wrong, so he has to use the code as u mentioned i.e. by adding the ids in the array and use them for delete request.

Comment: @ProgrammingTurtle THEN select the REAL answer that told you so

Comment: @ProgrammingTurtle cool, you should still bind the integer as an int :)

Comment: @Ray it doesn't matter even a little.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes it does.  Binding with 'i' properly protects the field from injection, but doesn't quote it.  Binding with 's' will quote it.  Quoting and integer then comparing it with an = MySQL then has to cast the the field from a string to an integer when doing the comparison in the where clause.  You should always bind your parameters correctly by type as need by your schema.

Comment: Never feed a troll, but... @YourCommonSense if it 'works exactly the same' then MySQL wouldn't need to cast during query parsing.  You can't even stay consistent in you're own trollings.

Comment: I am not a troll. Nor a fraud. You first posted this nonsense answer. THEN dared to excuse it with nonsense "it worked for the OP!". You did it by yourself, no troll forced you to. Nor I am a baby in the wood can be fooled with such a silly trick. This question is not on query parsing but on the deletion. FOR THE MATTER IN QUESTION IT WORKS EXACTLY THE SAME WAY.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I mentioned my original answer in a comment, which the poster indicated seemed to fix his issue.  I then moved it to an answer.  Then you began shouting 'fraud' like a child in tanturm.  Once Abhik brought my attention to the delete issue, I improved my answer and admitted what I missed.  Maybe if that had been your first approach to help me see what I missed before slinging insults, you wouldn't be comming off as some kind of threatening troll.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the ID in the form, you have a loop where you add the ID like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" />
```

This ID doesn't seem to have any relationship to the actual IDs in your database, it's just based on your loop counter. So, I wouldn't expect it to delete whatever it is that you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate the ID like that.

You'd have much more success selecting it from the database (as you did with the other fields.